# How do I set the directory or file path in S3 using AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Looking at the [`AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.html#) class, I don't see any way to specify a directory in my bucket.

For example, there is a directory images inside my bucket and a file named "first.png". I can set the key to "first.png" but that would only work if the file is on root directory of my bucket.

When I try to set the key to "images/first.png", it does not work either. How do I target files inside a directory using `AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest`?

Thanks

Comment: It should work with "images/first.png". What error message are you seeing?

Comment: No error messages but let me try again

Comment: If there is no error message, how do you know it is not working?

Comment: I was not able to see the file. Anyways, the fault is in my objective C file transfer code. So you are right Matt. Thank you!

Comment: Should I delete this question then?